# generic list collection c# html implementation

Tags: html, razor-pages

I'm working on a Razor Page and I need to implemtent my CreateDto in the HTML side.

I have already done it with a Enum class but now with the gernic list I don't know how.

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Crt.Job" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Crt.Job"
                        class="form-control" 
                        asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Jobtitler>()">
                    <option>Select type ...</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Crt.Job" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

the line " Html.GetEnumSlectList() " is where I tried to implement
my prop = public list from the class called dto

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Crt.Job" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Crt.Job"
                             class="form-control" 
        `I TRIED THIS`              asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Projekt>()">
                    <option>Select type ...</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Crt.Job" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

```
BUT THAT WILL NOT WORK
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code for your PageModel and the Projekt class definition.

Comment: `I have already done it with a Enum class but now with the gernic list I don't know how.`What do you mean `gernic list`?`Html.GetEnumSelectList` will help you add enum as options to dropdownlist.